# Find basis in Extension field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

[image]

I want to know that if we are asked to find the minimal polynomial, what are the steps? So if $F$ is a field and $\alpha$ is algebraic over F, first we need to find $[F(\alpha):F]$ and then according to the degree we found, we then know the degree of the monic minimal polynomial?

And for this question, how do we know that $[\Bbb Q((5^{1/3},(5^{1/2}i)):\Bbb Q(5^{1/3})]=2$? And how do we find the corresponding basis?

I know that for $\Bbb Q(3^{1/2},5^{1/2})$, the basis for it over $\Bbb Q$ is ${1, 3^{1/2},5^{1/2}, 3^{1/2}*5^{1/2}}$, but I don't know how to find the basis in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps an example will best illustrate how to find a minimal polynomial:

Let $F=\Bbb Q(5^{1/3})$ and $K=\Bbb Q((5^{1/3},(5^{1/2}i))$. Then you know that adjoining $5^\frac{1}{2}i$ to $F$ will give you $K$. So let $\alpha=5^\frac{1}{2}i$. Since $\alpha$ satisfies $x^2+5=0$, $[F(\alpha):F]$ is atmost 2. To show that it is actually true we need to know that $\alpha$ does not satisfy a smaller degree (non-zero) polynomial. And it doesn't, because any smaller polynomial will be linear and that will cause $\alpha\in F$ which is impossible because $F\subset \mathbb R$ is real and $5^{1/2}i$ is imaginary.

As for the basis, since $[F(\alpha):F]=2$, your basis will have exactly $2$ elements. Always let $1$ be the first element of your basis. Next, let $\alpha$ be another element. You know that $1$ and $\alpha$ are linearly independant over $F$ because $1$ is an element of $F$ and $\alpha$ is not!

Comment: I kinda get it. Can you do the example for finding the basis for $\Bbb Q(5^{1/3},5^{1/2}i)$ over $\Bbb Q$?

Comment: Try using the same method and post it as answer. I'll comment on it. Moreover you probably know a basis for $\mathbb Q(5^{1/3})$ over $\mathbb Q$ and I did $\mathbb Q(5^{1/3},5^{1/2}i)$  over $\mathbb Q(5^{1/3}$ so how can you combine them?

Comment: The basis for $\Bbb Q(5^{1/3})$ over $\Bbb Q$ would be ${1, 5^{1/3},(5^{1/3})^2}$ and according to your answer, we know that the basis for $\Bbb Q(5^{1/3}, 5^{1/2}i)$ over $\Bbb Q(5^{1/3})$ is ${1, 5^{1/2}i}$. Then we want to find $[\Bbb Q(5^{1/3}, 5^{1/2}i)]:[\Bbb Q] = [\Bbb (Q(5^{1/3}, 5^{1/2}i): \Bbb Q(5^{1/3})][\Bbb Q(5^1/3):\Bbb Q]$, which is equal to $2*3=6$. But after that, I only know the first four elements of the basis, how to find the rest 2 of them?

Comment: The first technique gave you three elements of a basis. the second gave you two elements. How do you think we will get $6$ basis elements? Not by merely putting them together in a list..

Comment: Oh $(5^{1/3})(5^{1/2}i)=5^{1/6}i$, but how do we get the degree?

Comment: You multiply the elements of the basis together.

Comment: The elements of the basis are $1, 5^{1/3}, (5^{1/3})^2, 5^(1/2)i$, I don't see how we can get degree 5 and 7 by multiplying them together

Comment: Where are $5$ and $7$ coming from?

Comment: It's in the example. "The basis for $\Bbb Q(5^{1/3}, 5^{1/2}i)$ over $\Bbb Q$ is ${1, 5^{1/2}i, 5^{1/3}, (5^{1/3})^2, (5^{1/6})^5i, (5^{1/6})^7i}$."

Comment: @J.doe I see.  When you multiply two elements with the same base, the exponents add, they do not multiply. So $1/2+1/3=5/6$ and similarly $1/2+2/3=7/6$.

Comment: You are right....Thanks!